# How to send byte array data to other activities?

Tags: android

I've been stuck on this problem for days. If any little comment that help would be saving one programmer...
I have this two A and B activities. 
A activity is a activity that calls B activity in **startActivityForResult()**. 
B activity is a Camera activity that has Camera added to the activity. And the pictures that B activity takes needs to be sent back to A activity.

The photos I take is received by **byte [] data** by PictureCallback. And here's the problem. I expect the user to take at least 2~3 (or more)pictures, so I tried to make those byte arrays is List form.

1. Bitmap List is impossible because it causes **FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION** error when its over 40kb.
2. **ArrayList< byte[] >** is not Parcelable, so its impossible to put in the Intent Extra data.
3. I tried to save every byte [] data of photos to intent Extra by for loop. But due to (I think) capacity problem, it refreshes the application when B activity is finished. (It is not caught on logcat becuase it doesn't crash the app)

I didn't include any codes because think it's not needed. If you are curious about it I will immediately show you any codes you like.

If any better ways, or little feedbacks on my trials would mean a lot to me. And be REALLY thankful. Thanks for reading!

A Activity

```
public class A_Activity extends AppCompatActivity{

private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 101;

private FrameLayout accidentFrame;
private FragmentManager manager;

......

ArrayList< byte[] > sending_list; 


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_accident_record);


    sending_list = new ArrayList<>(); 
     ....


    // button that moves to B Activity
    findViewById(R.id.btnCamera).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(A_Activity.this, B_Activity.class);

            ........

            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });

    //

  ....

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

             int size = data.getExtras().getInt("array_size");
             for(int i = 0; i<size ; i++){
                 sending_list.add(data.getByteArrayExtra("byte_array" + i));
             }

        }
    }
}



private void sendResult() {

    // There is a reason using map!
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<byte[]>> thisMap = new HashMap<>();

    thisMap.put("0", sending_list);


    Intent picturesData = new Intent();
    picturesData.putExtra("data_map", thisMap);

    startActivity(new Intent(A_Activity.this, C_Activity.class));
}
```

}

B_Activity (Camera Activity)

```
public class B_Activity extends AppCompatActivity{

 ....

Camera camera;
FrameLayout appCamera;

CameraSurfaceAdapter cameraAdapter;
Button btnCapture;
TextView btnFinish;


ArrayList<byte[]> byteArray;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_accident_camera);


    .....


    appCamera = findViewById(R.id.appCamera);

    if (camera == null) {

        camera = Camera.open();
    }


    cameraAdapter = new CameraSurfaceAdapter(getApplicationContext(), camera);
    appCamera.addView(cameraAdapter);


    // take picture 
    byteArray = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
    btnCapture = findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
    btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            takePicture();
        }
    });


    btnFinish = findViewById(R.id.btnFinish);
    btnFinish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

         if(byteArray != null){

              Intent dataIntent = new Intent();
              dataIntent.putExtra("array_size", byteArray.size());
              for(int i = 0; i<byteArray.size() ; i++){

                  dataIntent.putExtra("byte_array" + i, byteArray.get(i)); 
              }

              setResult(RESULT_OK, dataIntent);
              finish();

        }
    });
}


private void takePicture() {

    if (camera != null) {

        camera.takePicture(null, null, mPictureCallback);

    } else {
    }

}


Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {


        byteArray.add(data);

        camera.startPreview();

        savePhoto(data);

    }
};


.......


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {


    btnFinish.performClick();

}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();

    camera = null;
}
```

}

Comment: My thought is to use Fragment The fragment will help you in your case.

Comment: make both activities fragment you mean?

Comment: B activity make fragment.

Comment: Another easy but kind of dirty approach I would consider when sharing large data between activities is simply just store them in a singleton.

Comment: @AkioAlex
uploaded the code! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not pass the image. It's inefficient and you will hit size limits pretty quickly. Just pass the reference, as you received in `onActivityResult()` from Camera. Or if needed, store that image file somewhere (SD card, private storage) and pass the Uri to it. Do not pass binary blob.

Comment: thnx. I will just approach the problem differently. Thank you!

Comment: but what do you mean passing the reference?

Comment: It means that just save image on local storage for temporary. then send its url/path to next activity. open image from that url. Because passing Image into Byte array also slow down when new activity is open.

Comment: did it ! Thank u again :) 
Think I was doing such a foolish way

Answer (score 0):

Pass byte array into intent:-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
startActivity(intent);
```

Get Byte Array from Bundle and Convert into Bitmap Image:-

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");
```